# python remove words that start with '\u...'

Tags: python, regex

How do i remove all terms that starts with '\u...'

```
count_all = Counter()
for sentence in tweets[:100]:
    cleaned_terms = [term for term in preprocess(sentence.lower()) if term not in stop]
    count_all.update(cleaned_terms)

print count_all.most_common(5)
```

output:

```
#[(u'#halloween', 100), (u'\ud83d', 52), (u'\u2026', 28), (u'\ud83c', 24), (u'halloween', 14)]
```

Comment: Could you give a clear example of possible inputs and expected output? I am getting a bit lost here. You have "the code that cleans". Does that code not do what you want? If so, how (not?)

Comment: Those strings don't start with `'\u'`. What you see is the printable representation of an object, as given by the `repr` function.

Comment: How do i print it our in readable format?

Comment: I don't know the exact type that method is returning. You may have to write a loop yourself to print the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\uXXXX corresponds to a Unicode character (e.g., 2026 = a single character ellipsis, ...). The simplest option to find non-ASCII would be to just check if `ord(term[0]) > 255` in your comprehension, but whether that's actually what you want to do might depend on your particular use case.

Comment: How would you write that in my code? I want to keep the term if I actually understand and see the output as an English/readable term

Comment: `cleaned_terms = [term for term in preprocess(sentence.lower()) if term not in stop and ord(term[0]) < 256]`

Comment: thanks, it looks better. i still see some terms that look like this `u'\xe9'` after  doing the above. In these cases, how do i translate those terms as well?

Comment: Those are in the ASCII range, but aren't printable. Changing 256 to 128 should do the trick.

Comment: Though for good measure, you probably ought to do `32 < ord(term[0]) < 128` to get the rest of the non-printable ASCII.